# Cannot connect to homegroup in my network

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, network-printer, homegroup

When I am creating a homegroup on one computer, the other is not detecting the homegroup. Both running windows 10. 
Ping is reaching to other

Screen shots of my setup and results.

[image: My Network Diagram]

[image: Secont PC Not connecting]

Comment: Are the laptop and PC connecting to the same router? Whats are the IP addresses of the laptop and PC?